# Erro ao setar variável dentro de foreach

Tags: php

Tenho este pedaço de código no PHP. Quando envio para a base dados as imagens ficam separadas por `;` e os vídeos só mete `;` no último vídeo .

```
foreach($html->find('img') as $imagensdescricao) {

    $imagens1 .= $imagensdescricao->src;   
    $imagens1 = mysql_real_escape_string($imagens1.";");

}

foreach($html->find('iframe') as $videodescricao) 
    $videos1  .= $videodescricao->src;
    $videos1 = mysql_real_escape_string($videos1.";");
```

É assim que estou a enviar:

```
$sqlinsert="INSERT INTO eventos ( Titulo , Preco, Imagens , Datainicio , Datafim , Descricao , Local , Hora , Videos , Imagem) VALUES ( '$Titulo' ,'$preco' , '$imagens1' , '$datainicio' , '$datafim' , '$resumo' , '$local' , '$horario' , '$videos1' ,'$imagem')";
```

Comment: Isto não é erro algum com a base da dados o erro é que if, for, foreach sem `{}` só permitem uma linha e a tag phpmyadmin não tem nenhuma ligação com o problema, phpmyadmin é um software para gerenciar bancos, ele não tem vinculo algum com o mysql ou o seu código

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bem eu coloco os meus erros aqui e resolvo de imediato a solução para o meu problema foi colocar `{}`

```
foreach($html->find('img') as $imagensdescricao) {

    $imagens1 .= $imagensdescricao->src;   
    $imagens1 = mysql_real_escape_string($imagens1.";");

}

foreach($html->find('iframe') as $videodescricao) {
    $videos1  .= $videodescricao->src;
    $videos1 = mysql_real_escape_string($videos1.";");}
```